# Perl if conditional processing seems to not be working

Tags: perl, if-statement

Been on this for a week now.  Not able to make an if condition to work in perl.  Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = undef;

my $data = <DATA>;

$data =~ s/(\s+)/ /gi;
$data =~ s/\[|\]//gi;

while ($data =~ /:(?<end>\d+) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+)(?=:)/ig) {
    if (($+{start} - $+{end}) == 0) {
        $data =~ s/:(?<end>\d+) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+)(?=:)/:$+{end} $+{needed} $+{start}/i;
        print "\nFull match: '" . "$&" . "'\n";
        print "\nStart: '" . "$+{start}" . "'\n";
        print "\nEnd: '" . "$+{end}" . "'\n";
        print "\nDiff: '" . ($+{start} - $+{end}) . "'\n";
    }

}

#print "$data\n\n";

__DATA__

lorem          [1170:1540]
ipsum          [1540:2040]
dolor          [2040:2350]
sit            [2350:2510]
amet           [2510:2670]
consectetur    [2670:3130]
adipiscing     [3130:3240]
elit           [3240:3470]
quisque        [3550:4070]
egestas        [4070:4290]
magna          [4290:4570]
sit            [4620:4650]
amet           [4780:5390]
molestie       [5480:6660]
imperdiet      [6660:6890]
- velit
lectus         [6920:6950]
egestas        [7130:7530]
enim           [7570:7830]
non            [7830:8160]
ornare         [8160:8260]
eros           [8260:8600]
- neque
non            [8600:8890]
risus          [9120:9450]
aenean         [9450:9570]
venenatis      [9570:9820]
- hendrerit
- urna
- nec
- bibendum
nunc           [11210:11380]
lobortis       [11380:11470]
in             [11470:11710]
in             [11780:11810]
facilisis      [12960:13340]
urna           [13340:13460]
in             [13460:13920]
neque          [14070:14630]
bibendum       [14630:14930]
lobortis       [14930:15250]
- maecenas
- efficitur
- fermentum
eros           [17060:17450]
malesuada      [17450:17760]
posuere        [17760:17810]
nisi           [18050:18080]
- tristique
- sit
```

If I change the if conditional statement from above to any of the below variations, it still seems not to be working.

```
if ($+{start} == $+{end})
if (($+{start} - $+{end}) eq 0)
if ("$+{start}" eq "$+{end})")
```

The desired output is only the second match, which is ":8600 - neque non 8600"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. I don't _think_ that `while` loop is doing what you think it's doing. Because you're using `while` to iterate matches, but then applying a pattern replacement on all of `$data`. I think it's worth backtracking a bit and explaining what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The `$+{start}` and `$+{end}` you print are from the `s///`, but the `$+{start}` and `$+{end}` you compare are from the `//`. If you moved the `print` to before the `s///`, you'll see the `if` is working correctly.

Comment: As you said, I am iterating through all matches for the given regex and do a regex replace if the condition "start - end == 0" is met.

Comment: @ikegami I tried your suggestion, but it is still not working as intended.  What I want is to retain the first word that is prefixed by a 'minus space' or 'hyphen space', which in this case is '- velit' as you can see in the __DATA__.  The other print lines work okay, but if you uncomment the last print line, which prints out the $data, you will see that the output is missing the "- velit", which is what I want to retain because "6920 - 6890" is not equal to 0.

Comment: Oh I'm sure there are many other problems in the way of achieving what you want to achieve, whatever that is. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @Sobrique I think I am beginning to see what the problem is and what you are trying to suggest.  What I want to do is do a pattern replace **only** on the **current match** if the condition is met.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the subtitution, which doesn't have a global `/g` modifier, searches from the beginning of the string each time

- The first time around the loop the values 8690 ... 6920 are found, and skipped because the values don't match
- The second time around, 8600 ... 8600 is found, so the subtitution executes. But it finds the *first* occurrence of the pattern, and changes `:6890 - velit lectus 6920` into `6890 lectus 6920`
- The *third* time around, the global search starts at the beginning again because the string has been modified, so it now finds 8600 ... 8600 again, and the subtitution executes, this time replacing `:8600 - neque non 8600` with `8600 non 8600`

You have chosen a very awkward way of doing this. If you explained what it was you wanted I could help a little better, but your substitutions are making nonsense of the content of the file; for instance they are removing the colon `:` separator from between the two numbers, so there is no way of telling where to separate the resulting digit string

---

I would write this

There's no need to ascend back into Perl to check that the end and start values are the same; you can just use a backreference to match the same number again. And I think your named captures are confusing things rather than clarifying, for instance the `notneeded` capture needn't even be a capture, never mind being named

There's also no need for a Perl `while` loop as a simple `s///g` will find and replace all occurrences on its own

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

$data =~ s/\s+/ /g;
$data =~ tr/[]//d;

my $re = qr/ : (\d+) \s+ -\s[\p{alnum}'-]+ \s+ ([\p{alnum}'-]+) \s+ \1 /x;

my $n = $data =~ s/$re/$1 $2 $1/g;

printf "%d %s made\n", $n, $n == 1 ? 'substitution' : 'substitutions';
```

#### output

```
1 substitution made
```

Comment: I got the gist of what you are saying with the pointers by Tim and Sobrique.  Thanks for everybody.

Comment: All points raised are valid and taken. Could have used a back reference, just so happened that the code posted was part of some other code, which was modified.  In the other part of the code, backreferences cannot be used.  Your point is valid though. That particular capture is not needed and need not be named.  Your code would do what I needed to do, I guess.  As I said, my code is just a carryover of some other code where I need to do a replace conditionally.  In this particular case, your code does all with regex alone, which is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

So I added some additional debug code, and found something interesting: (the 2nd and 3rd lines, and the following print statement):

```
while ($data =~ /:(?<end>\d+) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+)(?=:)/ig) {
    my $start1 = $+{start};
    my $end1 = $+{end};
    print("start 1 is $start1\nend 1 is $end1\n\n");
    if ($start1 == $end1) {
        $data =~ s/:(?<end>\d+) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+)(?=:)/:$+{end} $+{needed} $+{start}/i;
        print "\nFull match: '" . "$&" . "'\n";
        print "\nStart: '" . "$+{start}" . "'\n";
        print "\nEnd: '" . "$+{end}" . "'\n";
        print "\nDiff: '" . ($+{start} - $+{end}) . "'\n";
```

Here is the output:

```
[myuser@myhost tmp]$ ./tmp.pl
start 1 is 6920
end 1 is 6890

start 1 is 8600
end 1 is 8600


Full match: ':6890 - velit lectus 6920'

Start: '6920'

End: '6890'

Diff: '30'
start 1 is 8600
end 1 is 8600


Full match: ':8600 - neque non 8600'

Start: '8600'

End: '8600'

Diff: '0'
```

As you can see, it's printing two groups of start1 and end1 for the first group of data, the 2nd of which actually matches, because it's incorporating the matching iteration with it as well. Does that make sense?

Your second regex is missing the 'g'...

```
$data =~ s/:(?<end>\d+) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+)(?=:)/:$+{end} $+{needed} $+{start}/ig;
```

Seems to fix the issue.

```
[myuser@myhost tmp]$ ./tmp.pl
start 1 is 6920
end 1 is 6890

start 1 is 8600
end 1 is 8600


Full match: ':8600 - neque non 8600'

Start: '8600'

End: '8600'

Diff: '0'
```

Comment: S tried your suggestion, still not working as intended.  Please see comment above.  A global replace is not what I am looking for but a conditional replace on a per-case basis. I need to do regex replace only if the condition matches for that particular case.  I am sure I am doing something wrong, but can't readily put my finger on it.

Comment: Well even if the global wasn't your goal, your first conditional incorporates an extra iteration of your search, that's why my version printed out two sets of "start 1/end 1" variables. I'd assume that's not what you're looking to do.

Comment: sharp-eyed @Sobrique.  Finally rectified the code with the very helpful pointers by you Sobrique and Tim.  What I did is to make all regex matches non-greedy and used only the current match for the substitution part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modified code which works correctly as intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = undef;

my $data = <DATA>;

$data =~ s/(\s+)/ /gi;
$data =~ s/\[|\]//gi;

while ($data =~ /:(?<end>\d+?) (?<notneeded>- [a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<needed>[a-z0-9\-']+?) (?<start>\d+?)(?=:)/ig) {
    if ("$+{start}" eq "$+{end}") {
        print "\nFull match: '" . "$&" . "'\n";
        print "\nStart: '" . "$+{start}" . "'\n";
        print "\nEnd: '" . "$+{end}" . "'\n";
        print "\nDiff: '" . ($+{start} - $+{end}) . "'\n";
        my $start = $+{start};
        my $end = $+{end};
        my $needed = $+{needed};

        $data =~ s/$&/:$end $needed $start/i;
    }

}

print "$data\n\n";

__DATA__

lorem          [1170:1540]
ipsum          [1540:2040]
dolor          [2040:2350]
sit            [2350:2510]
amet           [2510:2670]
consectetur    [2670:3130]
adipiscing     [3130:3240]
elit           [3240:3470]
quisque        [3550:4070]
egestas        [4070:4290]
magna          [4290:4570]
sit            [4620:4650]
amet           [4780:5390]
molestie       [5480:6660]
imperdiet      [6660:6890]
- velit
lectus         [6920:6950]
egestas        [7130:7530]
enim           [7570:7830]
non            [7830:8160]
ornare         [8160:8260]
eros           [8260:8600]
- neque
non            [8600:8890]
risus          [9120:9450]
aenean         [9450:9570]
venenatis      [9570:9820]
- hendrerit
- urna
- nec
- bibendum
nunc           [11210:11380]
lobortis       [11380:11470]
in             [11470:11710]
in             [11780:11810]
facilisis      [12960:13340]
urna           [13340:13460]
in             [13460:13920]
neque          [14070:14630]
bibendum       [14630:14930]
lobortis       [14930:15250]
- maecenas
- efficitur
- fermentum
eros           [17060:17450]
malesuada      [17450:17760]
posuere        [17760:17810]
nisi           [18050:18080]
- tristique
- sit
```